# closing realm across different files

Tags: java, android, realm

i'm new to an android project and unfortunately the old team has left and i'm left clueless.

the project is structured as follows

Activities , fragments , realm ( which contains crud files & DAO files as well )

mainActivity :

```
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.menu_drawer_activity);
                ButterKnife.bind(this);
                EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                String ChannelId = UAirship.shared().getPushManager().getChannelId();

                Realm.init(this);
                RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().schemaVersion(2).deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
                Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default
                realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);

                showInitalFragment();
                setUserInfoInNaviagtionDrawer();
                setupUI();
            }

// some logic

      @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
            realm.close();
            super.onDestroy();
        }
```

now inside crud files and doa this what happens :

CRUDfile1.java : http://ideone.com/fs0RYo

DAOfile1.java : http://ideone.com/1klhW8

now the problem is that there is a lof ot realm instances created and remain opened a lot of memory is taken and sometimes causes the app to crash and i'm unable to close them ( the app will crash hence the comments ). any ideas how should i fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now the problem is that there is a lof ot realm instances created and remain opened a lot of memory is taken and sometimes causes the app to crash and i'm unable to close them ( the app will crash hence the comments ). any ideas how should i fix this ?

Realm instances are reference counted, meaning on a given thread, there's actually only **one** open instance. But the instance is closed only if all "local Realm instances" are closed.

For example,

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
Realm realm2 = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm2.close();
realm.close(); // <-- this is when Realm is released for the given thread
```

In reality, they both point to the same "underlying Realm", even though they are treated as two different "local Realm instances".

So you don't run out of memory because of "opening too many".

---

You can however run out of memory and crash **if you open Realm instances on non-looper background threads and don't close them**.

So on background threads, you're supposed to see the following setup:

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
     // do things here
} // auto-close
```

or

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
       // ... actual transaction code here
    });
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

This whole `RealmObject.getRealmObject(Context)` thing looks completely wrong.

I've seen people do this, `Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(...)` this for example creates an instance you'll never be able to close, and you should be closing them.

Comment: Oh wow, your fellow mates map the `RealmResults` (which is a List) into an `ArrayList`, but they keep them as managed objects. And the `get` methods don't actually return a list, they take an input list that is modified to contain the new list.... wow this is super-duper bad. This is the worst of two worlds.

Comment: Actually, I'm more saddened by the fact that there is someone out there (you) who has to bother with fixing it just because whoever made it figured they should make things 4 times as complicated as the actual task. Technically you'd need to replace these `ArrayList`s with actual `RealmResults`, keep them as field reference and add ChangeListener to them to keep UI in sync. And on background threads, you should make sure you open/close the Realm, close in `finally {` block.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your methods in both classes from

```
{
    Realm realm = RealmObject.getRealmObject(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    <your-code>
}
```

to (if your minSdkVersion >= 19)

```
{
    try(Realm realm = RealmObject.getRealmObject(MyApplication.getAppContext())) {
        <your-code>
    }
}
```

or to

```
{
    Realm realm = RealmObject.getRealmObject(MyApplication.getAppContext()));
    try {
        <your-code>
    } catch (Exception e) {
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (realm != null) {
            realm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore you will close all realm instances.

Comment: i tried 
`public static void insertCollectionsObject(final BorrowUnsubscribedBundleResponse collectionObj) {
        Realm realm = getRealmObject(getAppContext());
        ArrayList<BorrowUnsubscribedBundleResponse.LstBorrowBundle> borrowBundles = (ArrayList<BorrowUnsubscribedBundleResponse.LstBorrowBundle>) collectionObj.getLstBorrowBundles();

         realm.close();

    } `

and would case the app to crash or not get data. i'll try what you suggested

Answer (score -1):

The best practice says keep all your methods to perform specific types of operations in single class to maintain easily and keep your File Structure Neat and Clean:

Add your realm queries in single controller class and realm instance in this controller class only:

```
    public class RealmController {

    private static RealmController instance;
    private final Realm realm;

    public RealmController(Application application) {
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public static RealmController with(Fragment fragment) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(fragment.getActivity().getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Activity activity) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(activity.getApplication());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController with(Application application) {

        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RealmController(application);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static RealmController getInstance() {

        return instance;
    }

    public Realm getRealm() {

        return realm;
    }

    //Refresh the realm istance
    public void refresh() {

        realm.refresh();
    }

    //clear all objects from Book.class
    public void clearAll() {

        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.clear(Book.class);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    //find all objects in the Book.class
    public RealmResults<Book> getBooks() {

        return realm.where(Book.class).findAll();
    }

    //query a single item with the given id
    public Book getBook(String id) {

        return realm.where(Book.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    }

    //check if Book.class is empty
    public boolean hasBooks() {

        return !realm.allObjects(Book.class).isEmpty();
    }

    //query example
    public RealmResults<Book> queryedBooks() {

        return realm.where(Book.class)
                .contains("author", "Author 0")
                .or()
                .contains("title", "Realm")
                .findAll();

    }
}
```

Now make one method to close realm instance of this controller class when thread changes or fragment/activity destroys:

```
 public void closeRealmInstance(){
    if(realm != null){
    realm.close();
    }
}
```

Now, you are good to Go. Access realm as below in Fragment:

```
RealmController realmController = new RealmController(yourContext);
BookClass bookObj = realmController.getBook();
realmController.closeRealmInstance();
```

Using above structure you will get your code simplified and you will know better what's happening in existing code. Enjoy Coding!!! Upvote if it helped.

Comment: No no no nono no nono NO. `RealmController` and the Ravi Tamada article is BAD. Stop citing it. Read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/how-to-use-realm-for-android-like-a-champ-and-how-to-tell-if-youre-doing-it-wrong-ac4f66b7f149).

Comment: Also `refresh()` was removed in 0.90.0. So even the example is outdated, considering Realm is at 3.0.0